# datepicker bootstrap not change value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

As same tittle , when i change date in datepicker , the value of it is not change 
I compare start_date with end_date. If start_date larger than end_date. It is note and change date of start_date or end_date

```js
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('#start_date').datepicker().on('changeDate', function (ev)
    {
        if($('#start_date').val() > $('#end_date').val())
        {
            alert("Start date is larger  end date");
        $('#start_date').datepicker('update',$('#end_date').val());
        }
    });
  
     $('#end_date').datepicker().on('changeDate', function (ev)
    {
        if($('#start_date').val() > $('#end_date').val())
        {
            alert("End date is smaller  start date");
            $('#end_date').datepicker('update',$('#start_date').val());
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="start_date" />
<input type="text" id="end_date" />
```

Thank guys.I use datepicker bootstrap latest at (eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker) , bootstrap v3.3.1 at (getbootstrap.com), jQuery UI - v1.11.2 - 2014-11-23 at (jqueryui.com) , jQuery JavaScript Library v1.10.2 at(jquery.com/)

Comment: which datepicker are you using?

Comment: I use datepicker bootstrap latest in (http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker) . and Bootstrap v3.3.1 (http://getbootstrap.com), jQuery UI - v1.11.2 - 2014-11-23(http://jqueryui.com) , jQuery JavaScript Library v1.10.2 (http://jquery.com/) .Thank

Answer (score 0):

How about this code

```
var nowTemp = new Date();
var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

var checkin = $('#start_date').datepicker({
    onRender: function(date) {
        return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
    }
}).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    if (ev.date.valueOf() > checkout.date.valueOf()) {
        var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
        checkout.setValue(newDate);
    }
    checkin.hide();
    $('#end_date')[0].focus();
}).data('datepicker');

var checkout = $('#end_date').datepicker({
    onRender: function(date) {
        return date.valueOf() <= checkin.date.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
    }
}).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    checkout.hide();
}).data('datepicker');
```

Check this working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/8eht1byj/1/)